# Optimizing the solution of the 2D diffusion (heat) equation in CUDA

Tags: cuda, nvidia, cuda-gdb

I have already checked earlier questions on SO about this issue but not able to see how it relates here.

I am solving 2d diffusion equation with CUDA and it turns out that my GPU code is slower than its CPU counterpart.

Here is my code:

```
//kernel definition
__global__ void diffusionSolver(double* A, int n_x,int n_y)
{

int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;


if(i<n_x && j <n_y && i*(n_x-i-1)*j*(n_y-j-1)!=0)
    A[i+n_y*j] = A[i+n_y*j] + (A[i-1+n_y*j]+A[i+1+n_y*j]+A[i+(j-1)*n_y]+A[i+(j+1)*n_y] -4.0*A[i+n_y*j])/40.0;


}
```

int main function

```
 int main()
        {
        int n_x = 200 ;
        int n_y = 200 ;       
        double *phi;
        double *dummy;
        double *phi_old;            
        int i,j ;

        phi = (double *) malloc( n_x*n_y* sizeof(double));
        phi_old = (double *) malloc( n_x*n_y* sizeof(double));
        dummy = (double *) malloc( n_x*n_y* sizeof(double));
        int iterationMax =200;                    
        for(j=0;j<n_y ;j++)
        {
            for(i=0;i<n_x;i++)
            {
            if((.4*n_x-i)*(.6*n_x-i)<0)
            phi[i+n_y*j] = -1;

            else 
            phi[i+n_y*j] = 1;
            }

        }

        double *dev_phi;
        cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_phi, n_x*n_y*sizeof(double));
        cudaMemcpy(dev_phi, phi, n_x*n_y*sizeof(double),
        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        dim3 threadsPerBlock(10,100);
        dim3 numBlocks(n_x*n_y / threadsPerBlock.x, n_x*n_y / threadsPerBlock.y);

        for(int z=0; z<iterationMax; z++)
        {
        if(z%100==0)
        cout <<z/100 <<"\n";;
        diffusionSolver<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(dev_phi, n_x,n_y);
        }
    cudaMemcpy(phi, dev_phi,n_x*n_y*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaFree(dev_phi);
    return 0;
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it runs slower than a simple CPU-only iterative method. I don't know much about profiler and until now I tried with `cuda-memcheck` which gives `0` errors. 
How can I know which portion of the code is performing slowly and speed that up? I am working on a Linux environment. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I would focus on correctness before speed here: you have changed the kernel compared to the last two times we have seen this same code and now you have a big correctness problem: in-situ updating of the array A introduces a read-after-write memory race. Further, your grid size calculations appear to be totally incorrect. If I am not mistaken you are launching 40000 times too many blocks!

Comment: @talonmies, I have checked code against standard results and it is working correctly. I was updating array A in situ because I thought if extra array is used to store old values it will be slower. I am not sure about grid sizes. that seems to be error. should it be dim3 numBlocks(n_x / threadsPerBlock.x, n_y / threadsPerBlock.y);?

Comment: @talonmies, calculation was slow because to many kernel calls were made than necessary(in this case 40000) as you mentioned. If you can put it as answer I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: You start your kernel `iterationMax` times. Why not start it once using a different grid structure and indexing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The worst problem I see is that you are launching far too many blocks for the size of the input array. At the moment you are computing the grid size as:

```
dim3 numBlocks(n_x*n_y / threadsPerBlock.x, n_x*n_y / threadsPerBlock.y);
```

which should yield a grid size of (400,4000) blocks for an input array of only 200x200. That is clearly incorrect. The calculation should be something like:

```
int nbx = (n_x / threadsPerBlock.x) + (((n_x % threadsPerBlock.x) == 0) ? 0 : 1);
int nby = (n_y / threadsPerBlock.y) + (((n_y % threadsPerBlock.y) == 0) ? 0 : 1);
dim3 numBlocks(nbx,nby);
```

which would yield a grid size of (2,20) blocks, or 40000 times fewer than you are currently launching.

There are other optimisations which you could consider making to the kernel, but those pale into insignificance compared with mistakes of this magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody is interested, I'm posting below a fully worked code concerning the optimization of the solution approach for the 2D heat equation.

Five approaches are considered, using:

1. **Global memory**, essentially the OP's approach;
2. **Shared memory** of size `BLOCK_SIZE_X x BLOCK_SIZE_Y` not loading the **halo regions**;
3. **Shared memory** of size `BLOCK_SIZE_X x BLOCK_SIZE_Y` loading the **halo regions**;
4. **Shared memory** of size `(BLOCK_SIZE_X + 2) x (BLOCK_SIZE_Y + 2)` loading the **halo regions**;
5. **Texture memory**.

Everybody can run the code and check out which approach is faster for his own GPU architecture.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "InputOutput.cuh"
#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

#define BLOCK_SIZE_X 16
#define BLOCK_SIZE_Y 16

#define DEBUG

texture<float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType>  tex_T;
texture<float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType>  tex_T_old;

/***********************************/
/* JACOBI ITERATION FUNCTION - GPU */
/***********************************/
__global__ void Jacobi_Iterator_GPU(const float * __restrict__ T_old, float * __restrict__ T_new, const int NX, const int NY)
{
    const int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ;
    const int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y ;

                                //                         N 
    int P = i + j*NX;           // node (i,j)              |
    int N = i + (j+1)*NX;       // node (i,j+1)            |
    int S = i + (j-1)*NX;       // node (i,j-1)     W ---- P ---- E
    int E = (i+1) + j*NX;       // node (i+1,j)            |
    int W = (i-1) + j*NX;       // node (i-1,j)            |
                                //                         S 

    // --- Only update "interior" (not boundary) node points
    if (i>0 && i<NX-1 && j>0 && j<NY-1) T_new[P] = 0.25 * (T_old[E] + T_old[W] + T_old[N] + T_old[S]); 
}

/******************************************************/
/* JACOBI ITERATION FUNCTION - GPU - SHARED MEMORY V1 */
/******************************************************/
__global__ void Jacobi_Iterator_GPU_shared_v1(const float * __restrict__ T_old, float * __restrict__ T_new, const int NX, const int NY)
{
    const int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ;
    const int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y ;

                                //                         N 
    int P = i + j*NX;           // node (i,j)              |
    int N = i + (j+1)*NX;       // node (i,j+1)            |
    int S = i + (j-1)*NX;       // node (i,j-1)     W ---- P ---- E
    int E = (i+1) + j*NX;       // node (i+1,j)            |
    int W = (i-1) + j*NX;       // node (i-1,j)            |
                                //                         S 
    __shared__ float T_sh[BLOCK_SIZE_X][BLOCK_SIZE_Y];

    // --- Load data to shared memory. Halo regions are NOT loaded.
    T_sh[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = T_old[P];
    __syncthreads();

    if ((threadIdx.x > 0) && (threadIdx.x < (BLOCK_SIZE_X - 1)) && (threadIdx.y > 0) && (threadIdx.y < (BLOCK_SIZE_Y ‐ 1))) 
        // --- If we do not need halo region elements, then use shared memory.
        T_new[P] = 0.25 * (T_sh[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y - 1] + T_sh[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y + 1] + T_sh[threadIdx.x - 1][threadIdx.y] + T_sh[threadIdx.x + 1][threadIdx.y]);
    else if (i>0 && i<NX-1 && j>0 && j<NY-1)  // --- Only update "interior" (not boundary) node points
        // --- If we need halo region elements, then use global memory.
        T_new[P] = 0.25 * (T_old[E] + T_old[W] + T_old[N] + T_old[S]); 

}

/******************************************************/
/* JACOBI ITERATION FUNCTION - GPU - SHARED MEMORY V2 */
/******************************************************/
__global__ void Jacobi_Iterator_GPU_shared_v2(const float * __restrict__ T_old, float * __restrict__ T_new, const int NX, const int NY)
{
    const int i = blockIdx.x * (BLOCK_SIZE_X - 2) + threadIdx.x ;
    const int j = blockIdx.y * (BLOCK_SIZE_Y - 2) + threadIdx.y ;

    int P = i + j*NX;           

    if ((i >= NX) || (j >= NY)) return;

    __shared__ float T_sh[BLOCK_SIZE_X][BLOCK_SIZE_Y];

    // --- Load data to shared memory. Halo regions ARE loaded.
    T_sh[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = T_old[P];
    __syncthreads();

    if (((threadIdx.x > 0) && (threadIdx.x < (BLOCK_SIZE_X - 1)) && (threadIdx.y > 0) && (threadIdx.y < (BLOCK_SIZE_Y ‐ 1))) &&
       (i>0 && i<NX-1 && j>0 && j<NY-1))
        T_new[P] = 0.25 * (T_sh[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y - 1] + T_sh[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y + 1] + T_sh[threadIdx.x - 1][threadIdx.y] + T_sh[threadIdx.x + 1][threadIdx.y]);

}

/******************************************************/
/* JACOBI ITERATION FUNCTION - GPU - SHARED MEMORY V2 */
/******************************************************/
__global__ void Jacobi_Iterator_GPU_shared_v3(const float * __restrict__ T_old, float * __restrict__ T_new, const int NX, const int NY)
{
    const int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ;
    const int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y ;

    const int tid_block = threadIdx.y * BLOCK_SIZE_X + threadIdx.x;     // --- Flattened thread index within a block

    const int i1      = tid_block % (BLOCK_SIZE_X + 2);
    const int j1      = tid_block / (BLOCK_SIZE_Y + 2);

    const int i2      = (BLOCK_SIZE_X * BLOCK_SIZE_Y + tid_block) % (BLOCK_SIZE_X + 2);
    const int j2      = (BLOCK_SIZE_X * BLOCK_SIZE_Y + tid_block) / (BLOCK_SIZE_Y + 2);

    int P = i + j * NX;           

    if ((i >= NX) || (j >= NY)) return;

    __shared__ float T_sh[BLOCK_SIZE_X + 2][BLOCK_SIZE_Y + 2];

    if (((blockIdx.x * BLOCK_SIZE_X - 1 + i1) < NX) && ((blockIdx.y * BLOCK_SIZE_Y - 1 + j1) < NY))
        T_sh[i1][j1] = T_old[(blockIdx.x * BLOCK_SIZE_X - 1 + i1) + (blockIdx.y * BLOCK_SIZE_Y - 1 + j1) * NX];

    if (((i2 < (BLOCK_SIZE_X + 2)) && (j2 < (BLOCK_SIZE_Y + 2))) && (((blockIdx.x * BLOCK_SIZE_X - 1 + i2) < NX) && ((blockIdx.y * BLOCK_SIZE_Y - 1 + j2) < NY)))
        T_sh[i2][j2] = T_old[(blockIdx.x * BLOCK_SIZE_X - 1 + i2) + (blockIdx.y * BLOCK_SIZE_Y - 1 + j2) * NX];

    __syncthreads();

    if ((threadIdx.x <= (BLOCK_SIZE_X - 1) && (threadIdx.y <= (BLOCK_SIZE_Y ‐ 1))) && (i>0 && i<NX-1 && j>0 && j<NY-1))
        T_new[P] = 0.25 * (T_sh[threadIdx.x + 1][threadIdx.y] + T_sh[threadIdx.x + 1][threadIdx.y + 2] + T_sh[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y + 1] + T_sh[threadIdx.x + 2][threadIdx.y + 1]);

}

/*********************************************/
/* JACOBI ITERATION FUNCTION - GPU - TEXTURE */
/*********************************************/
__global__ void Jacobi_Iterator_GPU_texture(float * __restrict__ T_new, const bool flag, const int NX, const int NY) {

    const int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ;
    const int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y ;

    float P, N, S, E, W;    
    if (flag) {
                                            //                         N 
        P = tex2D(tex_T_old, i,     j);     // node (i,j)              |
        N = tex2D(tex_T_old, i,     j + 1); // node (i,j+1)            |
        S = tex2D(tex_T_old, i,     j - 1); // node (i,j-1)     W ---- P ---- E
        E = tex2D(tex_T_old, i + 1, j);     // node (i+1,j)            |
        W = tex2D(tex_T_old, i - 1, j);     // node (i-1,j)            |
                                            //                         S 
    } else {
                                            //                         N 
        P = tex2D(tex_T,     i,     j);     // node (i,j)              |
        N = tex2D(tex_T,     i,     j + 1); // node (i,j+1)            |
        S = tex2D(tex_T,     i,     j - 1); // node (i,j-1)     W ---- P ---- E
        E = tex2D(tex_T,     i + 1, j);     // node (i+1,j)            |
        W = tex2D(tex_T,     i - 1, j);     // node (i-1,j)            |
                                            //                         S 
    }

    // --- Only update "interior" (not boundary) node points
    if (i>0 && i<NX-1 && j>0 && j<NY-1) T_new[i + j*NX] = 0.25 * (E + W + N + S);
}

/***********************************/
/* JACOBI ITERATION FUNCTION - CPU */
/***********************************/
void Jacobi_Iterator_CPU(float * __restrict T, float * __restrict T_new, const int NX, const int NY, const int MAX_ITER)
{
    for(int iter=0; iter<MAX_ITER; iter=iter+2)
    {
        // --- Only update "interior" (not boundary) node points
        for(int j=1; j<NY-1; j++) 
            for(int i=1; i<NX-1; i++) {
                float T_E = T[(i+1) + NX*j];
                float T_W = T[(i-1) + NX*j];
                float T_N = T[i + NX*(j+1)];
                float T_S = T[i + NX*(j-1)];
                T_new[i+NX*j] = 0.25*(T_E + T_W + T_N + T_S);
            }

        for(int j=1; j<NY-1; j++) 
            for(int i=1; i<NX-1; i++) {
                float T_E = T_new[(i+1) + NX*j];
                float T_W = T_new[(i-1) + NX*j];
                float T_N = T_new[i + NX*(j+1)];
                float T_S = T_new[i + NX*(j-1)];
                T[i+NX*j] = 0.25*(T_E + T_W + T_N + T_S);
            }
    }
}

/******************************/
/* TEMPERATURE INITIALIZATION */
/******************************/
void Initialize(float * __restrict h_T, const int NX, const int NY)
{
    // --- Set left wall to 1
    for(int j=0; j<NY; j++) h_T[j * NX] = 1.0;
}


/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int NX = 256;         // --- Number of discretization points along the x axis
    const int NY = 256;         // --- Number of discretization points along the y axis

    const int MAX_ITER = 100;   // --- Number of Jacobi iterations

    // --- CPU temperature distributions
    float *h_T              = (float *)calloc(NX * NY, sizeof(float));
    float *h_T_old          = (float *)calloc(NX * NY, sizeof(float));
    Initialize(h_T,     NX, NY);
    Initialize(h_T_old, NX, NY);
    float *h_T_GPU_result       = (float *)malloc(NX * NY * sizeof(float));
    float *h_T_GPU_tex_result   = (float *)malloc(NX * NY * sizeof(float));
    float *h_T_GPU_sh1_result   = (float *)malloc(NX * NY * sizeof(float));
    float *h_T_GPU_sh2_result   = (float *)malloc(NX * NY * sizeof(float));
    float *h_T_GPU_sh3_result   = (float *)malloc(NX * NY * sizeof(float));

    // --- GPU temperature distribution
    float *d_T;         gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_T,          NX * NY * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_T_old;     gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_T_old,      NX * NY * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_T_tex;     gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_T_tex,      NX * NY * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_T_old_tex; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_T_old_tex,  NX * NY * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_T_sh1;     gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_T_sh1,      NX * NY * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_T_old_sh1; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_T_old_sh1,  NX * NY * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_T_sh2;     gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_T_sh2,      NX * NY * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_T_old_sh2; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_T_old_sh2,  NX * NY * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_T_sh3;     gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_T_sh3,      NX * NY * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_T_old_sh3; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_T_old_sh3,  NX * NY * sizeof(float)));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_T,           h_T,     NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_T_tex,       h_T,     NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_T_sh1,       h_T,     NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_T_sh2,       h_T,     NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_T_sh3,       h_T,     NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_T_old,       d_T,     NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_T_old_tex,   d_T_tex, NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_T_old_sh1,   d_T_sh1, NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_T_old_sh2,   d_T_sh2, NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_T_old_sh3,   d_T_sh3, NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));

    //cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
    cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);

    gpuErrchk(cudaBindTexture2D(NULL, &tex_T,     d_T_tex,     &desc, NX, NY, sizeof(float) * NX));
    gpuErrchk(cudaBindTexture2D(NULL, &tex_T_old, d_T_old_tex, &desc, NX, NY, sizeof(float) * NX));

    tex_T.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    tex_T.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    tex_T.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
    tex_T.normalized = false;

    tex_T_old.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    tex_T_old.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    tex_T_old.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
    tex_T_old.normalized = false;

    // --- Grid size
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE_X, BLOCK_SIZE_Y);
    dim3 dimGrid (iDivUp(NX, BLOCK_SIZE_X), iDivUp(NY, BLOCK_SIZE_Y));

    // --- Jacobi iterations on the host
    Jacobi_Iterator_CPU(h_T, h_T_old, NX, NY, MAX_ITER);

    // --- Jacobi iterations on the device
    TimingGPU timerGPU;
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    for (int k=0; k<MAX_ITER; k=k+2) {
        Jacobi_Iterator_GPU<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_T,     d_T_old, NX, NY);   // --- Update d_T_old     starting from data stored in d_T
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif        
        Jacobi_Iterator_GPU<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_T_old, d_T    , NX, NY);   // --- Update d_T         starting from data stored in d_T_old
 #ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif
    }
    printf("Timing = %f ms\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    // --- Jacobi iterations on the device - shared memory v1
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    for (int k=0; k<MAX_ITER; k=k+2) {
        Jacobi_Iterator_GPU_shared_v1<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_T_sh1,     d_T_old_sh1, NX, NY);   // --- Update d_T_old     starting from data stored in d_T
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif        
        Jacobi_Iterator_GPU_shared_v1<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_T_old_sh1, d_T_sh1    , NX, NY);   // --- Update d_T         starting from data stored in d_T_old
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif        
    }
    printf("Timing with shared memory v1 = %f ms\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    // --- Jacobi iterations on the device - shared memory v2
    dim3 dimBlock2(BLOCK_SIZE_X, BLOCK_SIZE_Y);
    dim3 dimGrid2 (iDivUp(NX, BLOCK_SIZE_X - 2), iDivUp(NY, BLOCK_SIZE_Y - 2));
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    for (int k=0; k<MAX_ITER; k=k+2) {
        Jacobi_Iterator_GPU_shared_v2<<<dimGrid2, dimBlock>>>(d_T_sh2,     d_T_old_sh2, NX, NY);   // --- Update d_T_old     starting from data stored in d_T
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif        
        Jacobi_Iterator_GPU_shared_v2<<<dimGrid2, dimBlock>>>(d_T_old_sh2, d_T_sh2    , NX, NY);   // --- Update d_T         starting from data stored in d_T_old
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif        
    }
    printf("Timing with shared memory v2 = %f ms\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    // --- Jacobi iterations on the device - shared memory v3
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    for (int k=0; k<MAX_ITER; k=k+2) {
        Jacobi_Iterator_GPU_shared_v3<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_T_sh3,     d_T_old_sh3, NX, NY);   // --- Update d_T_old     starting from data stored in d_T
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif        
        Jacobi_Iterator_GPU_shared_v3<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_T_old_sh3, d_T_sh3    , NX, NY);   // --- Update d_T         starting from data stored in d_T_old
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif        
    }
    printf("Timing with shared memory v3 = %f ms\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    // --- Jacobi iterations on the device - texture case
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    for (int k=0; k<MAX_ITER; k=k+2) {
        Jacobi_Iterator_GPU_texture<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_T_old_tex, 0, NX, NY);   // --- Update d_T_tex         starting from data stored in d_T_old_tex
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif        
        Jacobi_Iterator_GPU_texture<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_T_tex,     1, NX, NY);   // --- Update d_T_old_tex     starting from data stored in d_T_tex
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif        
    }
    printf("Timing with texture = %f ms\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    saveCPUrealtxt(h_T,     "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Project\\Differential_Equations\\Heat_Equation\\2D\\DiffusionEquationJacobi\\DiffusionEquation\\CPU_result.txt",     NX * NY);
    saveGPUrealtxt(d_T_tex, "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Project\\Differential_Equations\\Heat_Equation\\2D\\DiffusionEquationJacobi\\DiffusionEquation\\GPU_result_tex.txt", NX * NY);
    saveGPUrealtxt(d_T,     "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Project\\Differential_Equations\\Heat_Equation\\2D\\DiffusionEquationJacobi\\DiffusionEquation\\GPU_result.txt",     NX * NY);
    saveGPUrealtxt(d_T_sh1, "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Project\\Differential_Equations\\Heat_Equation\\2D\\DiffusionEquationJacobi\\DiffusionEquation\\GPU_result_sh1.txt",     NX * NY);
    saveGPUrealtxt(d_T_sh2, "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Project\\Differential_Equations\\Heat_Equation\\2D\\DiffusionEquationJacobi\\DiffusionEquation\\GPU_result_sh2.txt",     NX * NY);
    saveGPUrealtxt(d_T_sh3, "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Project\\Differential_Equations\\Heat_Equation\\2D\\DiffusionEquationJacobi\\DiffusionEquation\\GPU_result_sh3.txt",     NX * NY);

    // --- Copy results from device to host
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_T_GPU_result,     d_T,     NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_T_GPU_tex_result, d_T_tex, NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_T_GPU_sh1_result, d_T_sh1, NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_T_GPU_sh2_result, d_T_sh2, NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_T_GPU_sh3_result, d_T_sh3, NX * NY * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    // --- Calculate percentage root mean square error between host and device results
    float sum = 0.f, sum_tex = 0.f, sum_ref = 0.f, sum_sh1 = 0.f, sum_sh2 = 0.f, sum_sh3 = 0.f;
    for (int j=0; j<NY; j++)
        for (int i=0; i<NX; i++) {
            sum     = sum     + (h_T_GPU_result    [j * NX + i] - h_T[j * NX + i]) * (h_T_GPU_result    [j * NX + i] - h_T[j * NX + i]);
            sum_tex = sum_tex + (h_T_GPU_tex_result[j * NX + i] - h_T[j * NX + i]) * (h_T_GPU_tex_result[j * NX + i] - h_T[j * NX + i]);
            sum_sh1 = sum_sh1 + (h_T_GPU_sh1_result[j * NX + i] - h_T[j * NX + i]) * (h_T_GPU_sh1_result[j * NX + i] - h_T[j * NX + i]);
            sum_sh2 = sum_sh2 + (h_T_GPU_sh2_result[j * NX + i] - h_T[j * NX + i]) * (h_T_GPU_sh2_result[j * NX + i] - h_T[j * NX + i]);
            sum_sh3 = sum_sh3 + (h_T_GPU_sh3_result[j * NX + i] - h_T[j * NX + i]) * (h_T_GPU_sh3_result[j * NX + i] - h_T[j * NX + i]);
            sum_ref = sum_ref + h_T[j * NX + i]                                * h_T[j * NX + i];
        }
    printf("Percentage root mean square error           = %f\n", 100.*sqrt(sum     / sum_ref));
    printf("Percentage root mean square error texture   = %f\n", 100.*sqrt(sum_tex / sum_ref));
    printf("Percentage root mean square error shared v1 = %f\n", 100.*sqrt(sum_sh1 / sum_ref));
    printf("Percentage root mean square error shared v2 = %f\n", 100.*sqrt(sum_sh2 / sum_ref));
    printf("Percentage root mean square error shared v3 = %f\n", 100.*sqrt(sum_sh3 / sum_ref));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a lot of integer multiplication and have a lot of global memory reads, both of which are slow in CUDA. I also imagine that there are not a lot of coalesced global memory reads.

The only way to speed up your kernel is to stage coalesced memory reads through shared memory and/or re-arrange your data so that you can index it without using lots of integer multiplication.

I don't have a great grasp of diffusion equations, but I don't think there is a lot of naive parallelism to be exploited. Take a look at the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) and the [Best Practices Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf) and maybe you'll get some ideas about how to improve your algorithm.

Comment: thanks for the reply maxywb, I don't have any idea about coalesced memory, probably I need to read about best practises